# Apperoseife - meaning

Tags: meaning, translation

[image]Please explain the meaning of "apperoseife".

There is no context, only one word. It's just a caption to the photo in the magazine.
I checked all dictionaries, no dice. I found this word in the magazine "IndustrieArchäologie 2/2014". This issue is about soap.

I hope it comes in handy, the photo shows a product carton with indication in Turkish:

> KARAKUŞ
>   Özel İmalat - Doğal
>   Hatay'ın Hakiki Zeytınyağlı
>   Defne Sabunu

Also there are 3 green blocks of solid unknown substance (maybe soap) in the photo.

Comment: Where did you find this word? In which context? Did you already google for it? What have you found? This is a board about German language. English is accepted for communication. Translations in any languages are not in the scope of this board.

Comment: I checked all dictionaries, no dice. I found this word in a magazine "IndustrieArchäologie". This issue is about soap.

Comment: I'll appreciate your explanation of this word in German.

Comment: The magazine seems to be originated from Switzerland - Apèro is a shortened form of Aperetif there and also used beyond the common German meaning (a drink) for a whole occasion offering drinks,  snacks and finger food - But why you'd want to have a special soap for this occasion, escapes me.

Comment: Hi, "tofro". Thank you for your reply. Are "Apèro" and "appero" synonyms in this case?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. And I got the accent wrong myself - It's Apéro. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ro_(Anlass) (But no mention of soap there ;) )

Comment: Apperoseife is enigma. Probably only God knows what it is. What do you think, if it can be just a scented (aroma) soap?

Comment: Apéro in swiss will never be written with double p. I know we are silly, but not so much!

Comment: Hmmm... this reminds me of a *soap opera*. <g>

Comment: Wird dort Apperoseife tatsächlich klein geschrieben? Appero könnte ein Firmenname sein und Apperoseife eine Wortbildung wie Bullrichsalz.

Comment: @IQV I appreciate your editing, but are you sure the turkish lines are correctly split?

Comment: Hi IQV, thank you for your reply and attention to this question. I've checked the turkish lines once more time and confirm its correct split.

Comment: @mtwde This are the original linebreaks of the OP, which didn't work with Markdown. And in the meantime OP did confirm, they are correct.

Comment: Please post the photograph.

Comment: Give me 15 minutes.

Comment: Done. Please enjoy the photograph.

Comment: @Alexander: actually adding the photo is a great idea, thank you for your effort!

Comment: It’s hard to tell the size, but if they’re small, on the order of 1–10 cm³, it could be related to [Apéricubes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ricube), small prepackaged cubes of flavored processed cheese.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As said in the comments there is presumably nothing like "Apperoseife" or maybe it refers to the manufacturer, but lets play Sherlock Holmes and take a wild guess:

clue a) IndustrieArchäologie 2/2014's title was "Geschichte der Waschmittel"

clue b) there are 3 green blocks

clue c) sounds like apperoseife, maybe a typo or company

clue d) turkish product carton

Therefore i think we are talking about [Aleppo-Seife](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo-Seife) / [Aleppo soap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo_soap) as its originated from syria, was invented around 800 and it is green.

**EDIT**

clue e) Defne translates to laurel (Lorbeer)

clue f) Zeytınyaglı translates to olive oil

clue g) Sabunu translates to soap

Olive oil & laurel are the two main ingrediants of Aleppo soap. Elementary, my dear Watson.

Ok, seriously:
As said before this answer was a wild guess for fun. But given the clues I'm pretty sure the "apperoseife" is some kind of Aleppo soap

**EDIT 2**

Looking at the new photo we can find the [german packaging](https://www.bakkalalisverisim.com/product-page/karakus-defne-sabun)

Print says:

> KARAKUS
>
> Sonderproduktion - Natürlich
>
> Lorbeerseife mit echtem
>
> Olivenöl aus Hatay

but ... most likely we will never know why it was called Apperoseife :/

Comment: So it's word and picture play? Good work, Holmes.

Comment: Typo ist eine bizarre These - nach meiner Zählung braucht man 4 Typos um von Aleppo auf Appero zu kommen. Außerdem frage ich mich, ob Du Fachmann für Industriearchäologie bist, um selbstgewiss sagen zu können, dass es es sicher keine Apperoseife gibt. Appero könnte ein Herstellername sein.

Comment: @userunknown ach, ich habe schon viele merkwürdigere Typos gesehen um das auszuschließen. Habs trotzdem editiert

Comment: "mtwde" - thank you very much. Your answer is the best suitable.

Comment: @userunknown Es ist nur 1 Tippfehler, wenn man zusätzlich 1 Gehirn-falsch-Einraster annimmt. Halte ich nicht für sooo unwahrscheinlich. Spracheingabe könnte auch der Grund sein. Alexa hat das falsch verstanden.

Comment: "Defne sabunu" translates to Daphne soap, a traditional kind of soap, AFAIK.

Comment: FWIW, [Apero soap](https://loveandpepper.co.uk/skin-care/vegan-friendly/soap-neroli-sweet-marjoram-witch-hazel)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Nice! At least there is 1 soap called like that :D . But I think we are looking for something like [this soap](http://www.el-ruha.com/urun/elruha-zeytinyagli-defne-sabunu/)

Comment: @mtwde: I know.

Comment: @tofro: Was ist denn ein Gehirn-falsch-Einraster? Ein Tippfehler ist das Tippen einer Nachbartaste, was hat das mit Gehirneinrasten zu tun? Und Alexa gibt es erst 2015.

Comment: @mtwde Interessanterweise wird auch in der referenzierten Anzeige "3 Stücke per Packung" erwähnt. Dieses Indiz spricht für das beworbene Produkt.

Comment: @userunknown Appero -> Areppo -> Aleppo . Denke das erste ist mit Falsch-Einraster gemeint

Comment: @mwde: Ursprünglich stand da "maybe a typo", nicht "maybe a typo after fundamental word reordering".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Nach dem Du Apero Soap gefunden hast, willst Du das nicht als Antwort posten? Das erscheint mir doch deutlich wahrscheinlicher, als Alepposeife und es wundert mich, dass die anderen nach diesem Fund ihre Antworten nicht zurückziehen.

Comment: @userunknown Die Apero Soap hinter dem Link hat weder in Form, Farbe, Herkunft oder Inhaltsstoffen etwas mit dem gesuchten gemein. Es gibt nur einen Hersteller und nichts weißt darauf hin, dass es eine historische Seife ist. Toller Fund, aber ich tippe also eher auf Zufall. Naja, wir scheinen auch unterschiedliche Vorstellungen zu haben was alles ein Typo ist. Ob Appero tatsächlich Aleppo heißen sollte sei mal dahingestellt. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass eine Seife aus Lorbeer und Olivenöl (siehe Link auf deutsche Verpackung in Antwort) aber eine dieser Art **ist** ist extrem hoch

Answer (score 1):

I am almost sure, that it is a missspelling of *Alepposeife*, [look at Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo-Seife) for more.

Comment: Hi, I am totally agree with you. Thank you.

Comment: Auch nachdem Rudy Velthuis Apero Soap gefunden hat (s. Kommentar u. Link u. mtwdes Antwort)?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly mean a product of this site:

http://www.antakyadefnesabunu.com/47/Urunler.html

soap is correct

but appero is surely wrong. May be you are looking for apollo soap.

Comment: There are quite a number of "Defne Sabunu". It is some kind of "Daphne soap", IOW, a traditional soap.

Comment: "Albrecht Hügli" - thank you. Your reply comes in handy as well.